# Как лучше создать свой электронный учебник?

Tags: книги

Доброго времени суток. Из-за курсовой работы встал вопрос о написании электронного учебника. Преподаватель разрешил пользоваться специализированными программами для этого дела. Единственное условие, что на выходе должен получаться редактируемый учебник. Собственно сам вопрос - кто сталкивался с данным вопросом, какие программы можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 2):

У меня был подобный вопрос, только со справочником материалов для сотрудников. Много-много материалов, которые постоянно обновляются. Перепробовал кучу всего, от обычного doc и pdf до  создания информационных внутренних лендингов.

Как ни странно, оказалось самым эффективным сделать сайт на googl и ограничить его теми людьми, которые пользуются информацией. Бесплатно, быстро, эффективно.

Comment: То есть просто написать учебник на html? Или я чего не так понял?
P.S. Да и форматы doc и pdf мне не подходят, ибо там должна подразумеваться навигация по учебнику.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/?hl=ru

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас буду ознакомляться...